# Angular custom validator causes scope variable to be undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm implementing a custom validator for a directive that checks the length of an array, but I'm having an interesting problem when I try and uncomment one of the lines of code in my validator:

```
angular.module("directives.tags", []).directive("tags", ["Tag", "$timeout", function(Tag, $timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            availableTags: '=',
            currentTags: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {

            // Snip

            $scope.updateSuggestionList = function() {
                var search = new RegExp($scope.tagInput, "i");

                $scope.suggestions = $scope.availableTags.filter(function(availableTag) {
                    if ($scope.currentTags.filter(function(currentTag) {
                            return availableTag.name == currentTag.name;
                        }).length == 0) {
                        return search.test(availableTag.name);
                    }
                    return false;
                }).slice(0,6);
            };

            // PROBLEM APPEARS TO BE HERE
            ctrl.$validators.taglength = function(currentTags) {
                return true; // <-- This works just fine
                return currentTags.length > 0 && currentTags.length < 6; // <-- This does not work at all
            };

            $scope.$watch('currentTags', function() {
                ctrl.$validate();
            }, true);

        },
        templateUrl: // snip
    }
}]);
```

When I try and use this line: `return currentTags.length > 0 && currentTags.length < 6;`, when currentTags.length should be 0, it returns undefined:

```
Error: $scope.currentTags is undefined
.link/$scope.updateSuggestionList/$scope.suggestions<@http://localhost:3000/js/app.js:1116:1
.link/$scope.updateSuggestionList@http://localhost:3000/js/app.js:1115:38
anonymous/fn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js line 13231 > Function:2:248
ngEventHandler/</callback@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:23411:17
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:15916:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:16016:20
ngEventHandler/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:23416:17
n.event.dispatch@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:3:6414
n.event.add/r.handle@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:3:3224
```

Yet, if I comment that line out and simply return true or false. It works perfectly, albeit, without proper validation.

Here is my directive's template:

```
<div class="tagger-container">
    <div class="wrapper" ng-class="{ 'active': areSuggestionsVisible }">
        <div class="tag-wrapper">
            <div class="tag" ng-repeat="tag in currentTags">
                [[ tag.name ]]
                <span class="remove" ng-click="removeTag(tag)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="tag-input"
               ng-model="tagInput"
               ng-style="{ width: inputLength + 'px'}"
               ng-keydown="tagInputKeydown($event)"
               ng-keyup="updateSuggestionList()"
               ng-focus="toggleSuggestionVisibility()"
               ng-blur="toggleSuggestionVisibility()" />
    </div>
    <div class="suggestions" ng-show="areSuggestionsVisible">
        <div class="suggestion" ng-repeat="tag in suggestions" ng-mousedown="createTag(tag.name)">[[ tag.name ]] </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how my directive is called:

```
<tags available-tags="data.tags" name="tags" ng-model="text.tags"></tags>
```

`data.tags` example:

```
[{ name: 'aTag', description: null, id: 1}, ..., ...]
```

Comment: You don't need to scope-bind to `ng-model` attribute (in fact, you shouldn't), since you `require: "ngModel"` - to access the value, use `ctrl.$modelValue` (and it could be `undefined` in the first digest cycle)

Comment: when is the `updateSuggestionList` called and how `currentTags` are updated?

Comment: error is thrown in `updateSuggestionList`. Couldn't figure out how validators affect it! Please post also the code which triggers the `updateSuggestionList` functio

Comment: Preethi added directive template.

Comment: @NewDev, so I tried using `ctrl.$modelValue` and I got the same result - it's empty and then undefined almost instantaneously. Can you tell me why not to scope bind to `ng-model`?

Comment: @EchoLogic can you also post the data being passed for `available-tags` and `ng-model` to the directive `tags` and its better if you post the full code of directive.

Comment: Simple arrays of objects. Make them whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In the Documentation for `$validate()`:

> Runs each of the registered validators (first synchronous validators and then asynchronous validators). If the validity changes to invalid, the model will be set to undefined, unless ngModelOptions.allowInvalid is true.

So I simply need to set `ngModelOptions.allowInvalid = true;`.